# SQL Server replication alerts delay

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

My problem is that for some reason there is a 15min delay between replication alerts (at the distribution agent), even when the underlying cause is the same transaction as what caused the previous alert. It's frustrating when I think that I've fixed the problem and then have to wait ages to see if it has any more to throw at me.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It seems to be a pause to see if the problem clears itself since changes made mid-delay do not fix the problem until the next cycle and I can't find any way of speeding it up. Our distribution database is on the same server as the publisher and the subscriber so surely it can't be taking that long for single transactions to be run?

For context: We use transactional replication for a storage database that retains records which have been deleted by a housekeeping process on the live system.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the alert has a delay to issue the second alert.

On Alert -> Options -> Delay between responses.

The lower the value, the faster it will send you the alert after a first alert is sent.
That is for preventing email overload.

Do Check it and then send us an answer.

**EDIT:**
Is it a Pull Subscription? Does the replication have any delays?

Comment: all of the alerts have a delay between responses of 0 mins, 0 secs :(

Comment: It's a push subscription, no delays that I'm aware of